# PHP websites with Docker

Tags: docker

I'm having a hard time understanding how to make bunch of PHP websites using Docker. I'd like to use Docker, so that I can scale this service. Also, each website is independent and executes arbitrary code, so each needs a kind of isolated chroot jail.

I just want to understand from a high level, what is required to do this kind of thing. I'm just beginning so please excuse the confusingness of this question:

Let's say I have an image that has nginx on it with php. So I can spin up say 10 containers with this image. I can load balance across those images. But I don't understand how I separate each "user" from each other.  If a request comes in to a particular container, then nginx invokes php to execute, how can I setup that php execution environment to be isolated - that is, not know about the other users?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "users"?  Are you referring to login sessions?

Comment: By users, I mean an actual php website.  I'd like it so it worked like this: i'd have say 5 hosts each with an nginx and php-fpm container (so 10 containers). But then lets say I'm hosting 10000 websites on this, but each website only gets 1 page view per year (ie. very low resources required). I want to know how to chroot jail or use apparmor change_hat to isolate php execution - the only time I know which php site to execute is when an http request comes in, I'll know from the "Host" http header

Answer (score -1):

You can create separate image that has nginx, php and website's code with assets for each website. One website - one image and one or more containers.